# Restricted control over company's laptop

Tags: company-policy, security

I have been recently hired as a security engineer on a company.

They provided me a MacBook Pro as a company laptop. As I always do in any computer in my possession - including in previous jobs - I rebooted in order to reinstall the operating system. I consider it to be good hygiene, since I don't know what's on the company's standard image, and by default I don't trust it. Besides, I expect to make my own choices regarding its initial configuration.

However, I noticed I am unable to enter the recovery screen because it is locked with a firmware password.

After requesting its removal, I was told by IT that this is a new company practice and they will not make any exceptions (other than laptops provided before this policy). The password will remain, and I am expected to use the base image only.

The way I see it, this is appropriate for non-tech-savvy users, but inappropriate in scenarios where autonomy is required, and employees are skilled, typically on technical teams.

I don't think any self-respecting security professional would be comfortable knowing that they do not have full control over their laptop, and that it was installed by someone else, with unknown defaults. Yes, it's the company's property and their decision, but as my main work tool, I should be able to use it anyway I need, including reinstalling the OS or booting from a live pen drive.

Effectively, I am being trusted to secure the company's business, but am not being trusted to secure my own laptop. This is a moral issue to me.

My questions:

1. Is my behavior unreasonable (or an overreaction)?
2. Is locking down a computer in this way for a security engineer commonplace in industry?
3. How do I resolve this without quitting?

I am perfectly aware that the company can choose anything they want, as it is their property, but security folk tend to be paranoid, and I am no exception.

I don't mean to turn this into a dispute, but I feel I will be so uncomfortable working like this that I am more likely to consider not remaining on this company.

Comment: Hang on... you are a security engineer... and think that you should be able to do whatever you want with company provided equipment without their approval? D'ya see the irony?

Comment: Ultimately, if you think you really need to do something, you should take it up with your boss who will then take it up with whoever he needs to get the job done

Comment: Policies are above people. If the policy must change is a different question. As a general concept though, the company must have some control over the laptots given to anybody.

Comment: Your focus should be not that you dont have control over the laptop as you say but on the tools that suposedly are missing. Your issue should be with the second part, and instead of requesting unlimited access on it, request what is missing to be officially installed/modified to your liking.

Comment: This sounds more like a rant, then a real question.

Comment: I sympathize.  Not having admin control over your primary work tool is a constant productivity hit.  But it's like every other policy; you have to obey it, but just make the consequences evident.  Don't work around problems, or hack in solutions... open lots of support tickets, and be honest with your manager about how you cannot test or run certain tasks because of this problematic policy.

Comment: @HorusKol: I don't find it ironic. It is usual, at least in my circles, to grant full access to the technical folk - developers, sysadmins, etc. Lockdown policies make sense when the job scope is limited to N installed applications, e.g. accounting, HR, marketing. Regarding taking it up with my boss, that was my next step; I'm awaiting an answer, which I should have next week.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere, that's probably the biggest lesson I'm taking from this. Indeed, this is important enough to me that I should have asked during interviews, but it wasn't exactly expected.

Comment: @BЈовић: it is partly a rant, yes; I couldn't find a better way to express it. But the questions are legitimate, and the wording reflects how I am thinking and feeling, since it is also relevant.

Comment: Since the question has been put on hold and it was already edited in a way that appropriately reflects my questions, what can be done now? Wait? Or it will remain like this?

Comment: Maybe that's a behaviour that needs to be reevaluated - in my circles we work to least privilege (even developers - even myself, the head of development and at my own instigation) - too often we hear about news about developers and administrators putting dumpfiles in places they shouldn't and creating significant data breaches. Or cowboy deployments breaking production... And so on...

Comment: @HorusKol: the least privilege you are talking about is appropriate in the context of an operating system. Obviously, I do not work as root or admin. This question is about the ability to do something as simple as reinstalling the operating system. It is _not_ about wanting root access - I would never accept to do my work on a computer where I did not have that.

Comment: Considering that this is a throwaway account and it looks like this thread will remain closed, I am deleting the cookies, and thus, the ability to continue posting. Thank you for your responses.

Comment: What did your boss say when you discussed this with him or her?

Comment: It's really common for corporate laptops to be locked down.  If you reinstall your own image you will be removing corporate tracking software, remote management tools, the ability to remote wipe the system if it is stolen with corporate IP on it, etc.  It's also MUCH easier to have a blanket policy that all corporate property runs corporate software than to get into an unending conflict about who is or is not exempt.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should realise that this is largely a question of responsibility. Since the IT department is responsible for the correct functioning of the machine they provide for you to use, they need a certain degree of control over the machine in order to be able to provide that guarantee. For them, this has nothing to do with you personally: they are providing a laptop to an employee of the company and are treating you like any other employee.

While I understand that distrust is an occupational hazard of a security engineer, I would advocate that when it comes to your own company's employees, you employ an "innocent until proven guilty" attitude. If you have a need for certain configuration of the machine, with certain tools installed and certain access rights, make a request for that configuration through the normal channels within the company. Only when the normal process fails do you have a reason to go to your manager and explain why and how the current situation prevents you from doing your job properly.

I can understand wanting full control over your own personal machine, or a machine that is in your domain of responsibility, but for a machine provided to you by someone else it seems unrealistic to expect full control. Anecdotally, I also fail to see how a pre-imaged machine would prevent you from doing your job: I've worked with security engineers that had barely any control over their own machine, they simply worked with their company's IT department in order to get their machine to the state they required.

Answer (score 18):

I doubt that letting them know your feelings are hurt is going to do much good.

If you have legitimate job functions that you can't perform because of this policy, then that's how you need to approach it with your management.

> With this policy in effect, I am unable to do X, Y and Z, which are critical to my role as a security engineer. I need an exception or some other work around to this policy in order to do my job.

And let them take it from there. It's useless for you to simply rail at the IT department. If they violate the policy for you, then it's on them if it gets discovered. Whoever has the power to make the exception, it's going to be up to them.

Comment: This is absolutely the right approach.  Ask for what you NEED not what you WANT.

Answer (score 13):

> am not being trusted to secure my own laptop

It's not your laptop, it is a tool the company have provided you in order to do your job.  However, I do sympathise.  It's normal for companies to have a standard image.  And I agree, when handing out a laptop to a generic user I would usually ensure quite a few restrictions were applied so that users didn't screw  with the machine.

If you need specific tools, you can and should request them.

What I recommend you do in the first instance however is - go and talk to your Manager, explain explain *why* you need/want it configured in a particular way, and ask if it is possible to have the restrictions lifted.  If your manager OK's it, then *they* should go back to IT and instruct accordingly, at which point the IT team can and should work with you to get the setup you need.

However, if your Manager says no, then that's the answer.  And you have to accept it.

Comment: "It's not your laptop" - I acknowledged this, at least twice, in the initial post. "go and talk to your Manager" - I did that today, and am expecting an answer. My manager agrees with me (thankfully), but he has to request the IT department for an exception, which they already refused once. I'm expecting a new answer, through him, which should be due next week.

Comment: @user74326 I know you acknowledged it, I didn't suggest otherwise, but it is a vital point as far as the IT Department is concerned.  Anyway, seeing as the Manager agrees with your view and he has said he will take care of it, it's a good result.  Good luck with the IT Dept - as your manager is instructing them, they are more likely to honour your wishes.

Comment: sadly, they didn't, so I'm left working on a computer I can't trust. It's not the end of the world, but makes me uncomfortable enough to think about moving to a different company. It's funny how the human psyche works.